# Pageant doesn't work with tortoise SVN and putty authentication

Tags: ssh, putty, svn, tortoise-svn, pageant

I followed this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoKHoRWu4EE) to try to install tortoise svn on Windows and commit on a unix remote server.

I don't want tortoise to ask me for my password on every commit. This tutorial works fine, but even when pageant is configured with a correct key, I have to give my password for a user which is not root.

What am I missing?

EDIT :
I tried to `.ssh/authorized_keys` in my `/home/{user}` I have tried the tutorial again with these params and chmod my files with 600 / 700, but still nothing works. Putty / Tortoise keep asking me for my password. I have read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

- generate a keygen dsa or rsa with your password like tutorial in the question
- Your user has to have his own .ssh directory in his home dir.
- It's better for mind's sake to call your rsa/dsa key = id_rsa or id_dsa
- don't forget if you still have issues you can debug on debian : `ssh -v -l {user} {ip server or remote server}`
- do your thing with Putty and pageant key...
- start new session and VOILA !!

Regards